# Right click not working in Excel2013

Tags: excel-2013

Right click is not working for me in excel 2013. I am unable to add or delete sheets plus the formatting menu. Please help

Comment: it could be locked by protection mode

Comment: Its the same even if i open a new blank copy.

Comment: copy your problem picture , it will be useful to recognize your problems ,thanks

Comment: Problem is simple. The right click is disabled in excel. Excel doesnt respond when i click the right button of my mouse. Even if i copy the picture it would be the same

Answer (score 2):

The below link shows two methods for fixing this.

[Fix Right Click Issue](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/grayed-out-right-click-menu-options/04de39d7-a389-488c-91bc-be69b8243214?auth=1)

1)Go to the VBE (Alt/F11), press Ctrl/G, enter this:
commandbars("Cell").Reset

2)Go to regedit and delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office|12.0\Excel\Options

Comment: Thanks for the reply everyone.

Comment: I tried the above solution but did not workout. But i did try one more which actually worked. I ll post the code here

Comment: Method #1 worked for me.  I followed the similar instructions I found here:  [right-mouse-click-doesnt-work](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/357080-right-mouse-click-doesnt-work.html)

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old post....but in case anyone has this issue and has Essbase installed....

I went to the options menu in Essbase, clicked on the Global tab, and selected 'Limit to Connected Sheets' n the 'Mouse Actions' options. That seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

All - I've been struggling with this in Excel 2010 ever since I ran some old VBA from a 2003 Excel file.  In that file, the code was written such that all right-clicking was disabled but never turned back on before exiting the file!

I've written a bit of VBA that should fix all command bar issues.  I'd appreciate any feedback on this - it worked well for me and I've only tested it on my system with Excel 2010 (that's my disclaimer).

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Application.CommandBars.Count

    On Error Resume Next

    With Application.CommandBars(i)
        .Reset
        .Enabled = True
    End With

Next i
```